# jtextpane doesn't wrap text

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap

I've got a problem with **JTextPane**. I need to mark some parts of text with specified color, so I've decided to use JTextPane and html tags to decorate my text. JTextPane  is inside JScrollPane, and JScrollPane is inside JSplitPane:

```
JTextPane jtp=new JTextPane();
jtp.setContentType("text/html");
JScrollPane scr=new JScrollPane(jtp);
JSplitPane leftRight=new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scr, someOtherComponent);
```

Also, after setting text into **jtp** I've noticed that it wraps uncorrectly.

So, could you advice me how to solve my problem, or, maybe offer a better solution?

I have decorate the text using html:

```
<FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow">next marked</FONT><b> embolden</b> normal<FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow"> next marked</FONT>
```

maybe there are any other swing components that helps do such simple text decoration?

P.P.S. Here is part of my code:

```
    originalTextArea=new JTextPane();        
    originalTextArea.setFont(font);
    originalTextArea.setContentType("text/html");
    originalTextArea.setText("dhjfsfdjnkjfgfjkgkjfngfdkjnjfdgjfdngfdkjgnkdngjgnjkgfgf");

    processedTextArea=new JTextPane();        
    processedTextArea.setFont(font);
    processedTextArea.setContentType("text/html");              

    JScrollPane originalTextScrollPane=new JScrollPane(originalTextArea);

    JScrollPane processedTextScrollPane=new JScrollPane(processedTextArea);
    JTabbedPane processedTextAndVocPane=new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP, JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    summarizedTextAndVocPane.add("Processed text",processedTextScrollPane);

    JSplitPane leftRightSplitPane=new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, originalTextScrollPane, processedTextAndVocPane);
    leftRightSplitPane.setDividerLocation(0.5);
    leftRightSplitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);        

    mainFrame.add(leftRightSplitPane);
```

After input text into `originalTextArea` it doesnt wrap at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "wraps incorrectly"?

Comment: I mean - It doesn't wrap my text at all. I don't need horizontal splitter, I need all text to be wrapped by width of jtp.

Comment: I did a quick test with your code and it wraps fine. Did you show us all relevant code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: text will only wrap on white space characters.
you show a big long string with no breaks - that will not wrap (?)

Comment: Thanks :) Understood. But is there ability to do non-whitespace characters wrapping?