# Java - How to set max-width for <table> in JTextPane?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jtextpane

I have a `JTextPane`, with html content :

```
    Pane = new JTextPane();
    Pane.setEditable(false);
    Pane.setContentType("text/html");
    Pane.setEditorKit(kit);
    Pane.setText("<html><body><div id='content'></div></body></html>");
    doc = (HTMLDocument) Pane.getStyledDocument();
    content = doc.getElement("content");
```

I add my html element in runtime with :

```
doc.insertBeforeEnd(content, "<table class = 'text'><tr><td>"+text+"</td></tr></table>"); // text is input from user
```

here is CSS that I use :

```
    styleSheet = doc.getStyleSheet();
    styleSheet.addRule("body{background-color:#FFFFFF; margin 0%;}");
    styleSheet.addRule("#content {margin: 0% 10%; width : 80%; }"); // I set them to bring element that will add at the center of `jtextpane` but it did't work!
    styleSheet.addRule("table{ max-width: 60%;}"); // I set this to prevent table with long width, but it didn't work! 
    styleSheet.addRule(".text{background-color:#E2EAF3;margin : 2px;padding : 1px 2px; border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: #D5D3CD;text-align: right;}");
```

also I use HTMLEditorKit defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533451/jeditorpane-linewrap-in-java7/17534943#17534943) to wrap my text.

How can I set CSS property to reach my goals.

- I want to set max size for the width, so if the text size is longer it wraps, and if it is shorter then the background fixed to its content.

note : the code that i use for creating HTMLEditorKit works fine for wraping text, problem is to set max-width. (now it wrap when it reach to `JTextPane` width)

Comment: have to wait for comment/answer by StanislavL or Andrew Thompson

Comment: @mKorbel I know how to restrict width of table but the problem is getting the max-width value from the style

Answer (score 0):

The `max-width` property cannot be defined for tables, rows or cells ([Details on W3 here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width)). You should use `width` instead.

Comment: From the link you provided  - property 'max-width'

Applies to:   all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row groups

Comment: I have interpreted the W3 documentation that it SHOULD work on table .. And it indeed seems to work out fine in EI11, Chrome V41, and Firefox V36.